# LorDModUE - How to configure

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, kernel

I have installed Lordmodue* to under volt my android device by downloading the .zip, booting into recovery mode, browsing the sdcard and selecting the .zip file.

The install was successful and under my phone settings it says my kernel is the LordmodUE kernel.

How can I actually set the settings for this kernel though, how can I set my under voltage settings?

*HTC DesireHD running Cyanogenmod 7.2 and Clockwork recovery mod

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need is here; http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1085725

There you can download the kernels, and the scripts and Lordmodue app to use them.